# Interface/design patterns for CRUD operations on components of parent class

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, interface, wsdl

I have a parent class, ProcessDefinition, that is generated from WSDL. It has over a dozen component classes. My requirements are:

- Extract an existing definition from the database
- Insert a new definition into the database
- Update an existing definition(could require inserts, updates, deletes on the components of the definitin) in the database
- Delete a definition from the database

The extraction is easy, as I check the database for the existence of each component and add to the definition if it exists. For this I intend on using an interface with a method

```
public interface ComponentDAO 
{
 public void addComponentToDefinition(ProcessDefinition definition, String   environmentName);
}
```

I will provide an implementation for each component, it will extract its component information from the database if it exists, create the required class and set it in the definition.

In spring I will configure a list of that interface and plug in each implementation, then in my master DAO class I can just do the following

```
ProcessDefinition definition = new ProcessDefinition()
definition.setProcessID(someID);
for (ComponentDAO c: this.getComponentDAOs)
{
  c.addComponentToDefinition(definition);
}
```

This is easy to extend and does not require me to touch any existing classes if I add a new component. However when updating a component or creating a new component, I need to know the component class, ie

```
public void update(ProcessComponentA component, String   environmentName);
public void update(ProcessComponentB component, String   environmentName);
```

Using generics, I can define the interface as something like

```
public interface ComponentDAO<T>
{
 public void addComponentToDefinition(ProcessDefinition definition, String   environmentName);
 public void updateComponent(T component);
}
```

This keeps the ComponentDAO implementations clean, but then in the master class that calls the interface I would have to define the list of ComponentDAO in raw type, no type casting is required but the compiler cant do complete type checking and results in the warning about parameterizing raw types.

Is there a design pattern that I should be using for this? Assume I am overlooking hibernate or any other ORM framework.

Comment: By IUD do you mean CRUD?

Comment: Yes, was thinking in SQL :) updated the title.